# Run generic groovy script assertion in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertion

Is it possible to / how do you run a groovy script from a SoapUI assertion without copy/pasting the script into all of your test steps where you need the same script executed? Is it possible to write a script outside of the assertion and run the script like you are calling a method? So that you can reuse the assertion script in multiple test steps.

So far, I've tried to call a groovy test step from within the assertion, but the `run()` method requires a `testRunner` variable which is unavailable from within the assertion. I've also tried to write a groovy script *as a subsequent test step* (not an assertion) that calls another groovy test step script, but I was unable to transfer the response from one test step to the next (Honestly, I'd rather not create test steps that are really just assertions).

Note: this is not a duplicate of [How to create variables in soapui test case that can be accessed across all test steps - groovy test step & script assertion test step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308998/how-to-create-variables-in-soapui-test-case-that-can-be-accessed-across-all-test) because that question pertains to storing properties, not reusing scripts.

Comment: Are you looking for the "Script Library"? https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html#2-Groovy-Script-Library

Comment: @SiKing 's comment should, IMHO, be the answer.  I've wrote several assertion classes, but I wrote them in Java and stored them in the scripts folders of the SoapUI install.  You still need a groovy step in your test to call the external script, but if your checks change, you only need to update the external script in one place.

Comment: @ChrisAdams the solution needs to be portable, i.e., the project xml will be handed off to multiple people. Separate files loaded into soapui as libraries seems like it would add a layer of complexity to the portability. I'd really like the solution to be visible (and editable) on the project layer and in the SoapUI screen itself.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally figure out my 2nd approach: add another groovy script as a subsequent test step that has assertions and passes the response. The script is:

```
context.response = context.expand('${MyTestStep#Response}') // store response to context variable
Object result = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases['Validate Response'].testSteps['Validate Response'].run(testRunner, context)

if(result.getError() != null) {
    log.error("error", result.getError())
    assert false
}
assert true
```

`MyTestStep` is the test step before the groovy script. `Validate Response` is the name of the test case of the groovy script which is also called `Validate Response` and is executed via the `run` method.

Comment: If you use Ready API (Pro) you can create a script library that you call like functions

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if my manager ever gives me the SoapUI Pro green light.

Comment: No need for "assert true".  Better form is to assert your predicate like this: "assert result.getError() == null : result.getError()"

Comment: True, `assert true` was superfluous. I removed it. The `assert false` remains because I need to log the error before throwing the false assertion.